# Dockerfile throwing an error "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My docker file looks like

```
FROM grpc/python
CMD ["/bin/ls /"]
```

It is throwing an error:

```
container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/ls /\": stat /bin/ls /: no such file or directory"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/ls /\": stat /bin/ls /: no such file or directory".
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the command from the arguments:

```
CMD ["/bin/ls", "/"]
```

`CMD` accepts the following formats:

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)
CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)
```

Answer (score -2):

You have extra space after `ls` in `CMD` command on second row

Comment: thats because i intend to ls the root directory.